# I need to capture Image and display it in another activity

Tags: android, camera

I have an activity that starts the camera API. 
I want to press the button (named by id "cptr_1") and take a picture and display it in another activity (PhotoPreview.class) where I can add photo effects.
I just need the code for:

```
    ImageButton capture_1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.cptr_1);
    capture_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

And then how to transfer that image to PhotoPreview.class

Answer (score 1):

You can take photo with the camera app of the device.

So when you click:

```
    static final int ImageValue= 1;

    ImageButton capture_1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.cptr_1);
        capture_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent takepic = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
               if (takepic.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
               startActivityForResult(takepic, ImageValue);
               }
            }
        });
```

Once capture is completed get the image back from the camera application

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ImageValue && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
       }
}
```

Then send `Bitmap` to another activity.

Inside the activity that starts the camera API write:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PhotoPreview.class);
intent.putExtra("GetBitmap", bitmap);
```

Inside `PhotoPreview.class` write:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("GetBitmap");
```

Also you may need to add those permissions to Android Manifest

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="true" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: its all good except one thing.. "bitmap" in ("GetBitmap", bitmap); wont resolve..
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = imageBitmap;

Comment: then send bitmap to another activity

Answer (score 0):

either you can use an Intent to take picture or use a custom camera class
for [camera intent](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) for [custom camera class](http://archive.oreilly.com/oreillyschool/courses/android2/CameraAdvanced.html)

if u already have a custom camera class, you can use this code`Camera cam = Camera.open(cameraId);

```
capture_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {

            cam.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
});


private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        try {

            File mediaFile = new File("file path/filename.jpg");

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            cam.startPreview();


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
};`
```

Comment: Thank you I will take a look.. I already build the camera though with surface view.. All i want is the code to take photo and display it...